# Cron Jobs with C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cpanel, cron-task

This is noobish but I am totally confused. I cannot find a good Google Article to know every small detail about Cron Jobs and using them in asp.net coding[with C#]. I am new to Web Development, that may be my problem.

What I want to do is to Run a piece of Code everyday at a fixed time [midnight GMT, maybe]. The code will actually update a file in the server, which I think is okay. But I am totally unsure about scheduling it. Note that, I am using Heliohost which supports cPanel with 2 cron jobs per 24 hours. I am totally confused. What do I need to know deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

I use Hudson for this, now called jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/) ,  first generate  console programs. In jenkins you can configure the time and period to execute exe program, bat program, shell, etc.. it's really fantastic for this purpose.

Note: jenkins is not only for scheduled  task, its main function is for continuous integration.